# How can I read a number from file?

Tags: perl

In my script, I've got a variable called `$monthRaed`.

In a file "month.txt", there is a number (3) corresponding to a month.

But, when I read the file "month.txt" and place the result into `$monthRaed`, I get a GLOB error.

Here is what I've done:

```
open $MONTH, "+<", "month.txt";
$monthRaed = $MONTH;
```

Then if I do a `print $monthRaed;`, I get this error: **GLOB(0xf796c8)**

I need a number (the one stored in the file) for a comparison with current month coming out as a number from a localtime function.

Comment: You should probably not use `+<` open mode, because it is more trouble than it is worth, and it probably doesn't do what you want in the long run. Instead, print to a tmp file, and move the file afterwards.

Comment: I don't really understand why you thought your code would work. Where did you get that code from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
 $monthRaed = $MONTH;
```

to:

```
 $monthRaed = <$MONTH>;
```

[Files and I/O](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html#Files-and-I/O)

Comment: The first assigns a filehandle to the variable, (so `GLOB(...)`), and the second uses the `readline(FILEHANDLE)` in its `<FILEHANDLE>` shortcut form.